# Codename One push notification type 4 crashes on iOS

Tags: codenameone

I'm currently trying out push notifications on iOS. When sending notifications of the type 4, the app crashes directly when the app is running. If it is not running, the push notification is shown correctly, but when clicking on the notification the app crashes right when starting with the following exception:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17fd5aa0'**

Full log from my iPad:

```
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von TCApp[562] <Warning>: Received notification while running: {
        aps =     {
            alert =         {
                body = "Test Body";
                title = "Notification Test";
            };
            sound = default;
        };
    }
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von TCApp[562] <Error>: -[__NSCFDictionary UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17fd5aa0
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von TCApp[562] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17fd5aa0'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (0x22efb91b 0x22696e17 0x22f012b5 0x22efeee1 0x22e2a238 0x36511 0x38ed3 0x27723e01 0x27712ecb 0x2459ec07 0x2459eab9 0x2459edb9 0x22ebddff 0x22ebd9ed 0x22ebbd5b 0x22e0b229 0x22e0b015 0x243fbac9 0x274dd189 0x4671af 0x894e3 0x1da62b 0x434187 0x4341bf 0x29e58)
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von SpringBoard[47] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:de.mypackage.in.TCAppcn1[0x812c][562]) <Notice>: Service exited due to signal: Abort trap: 6
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von SpringBoard[47] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:de.mypackage.in.TCAppcn1[0x812c]' crashed.
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 1764032310646: id=de.mypackage.in.TCAppcn1 pid=562, state=0
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von ReportCrash[564] <Error>: assertion failed: 13F69: libsystem_trace.dylib + 15927 [FCFC8D6B-F8E1-3577-84A7-8A591C88D819]: 0x0
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von Unknown[564] <Error>: 
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von ReportCrash[564] <Warning>: os_activity_diagnostic_for_pid() failed!
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von ReportCrash[564] <Notice>: Formulating report for corpse[562] TCApp
Jun  8 15:31:56 iPad-von ReportCrash[564] <Warning>: Saved type '109(109_TCApp)' report (5 of max 25) at /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/TCApp-2016-06-08-153156.ips
```

I'm sending the request with postman in url encoded format to the new push server https://push.codenameone.com/push/push. (I get the same exception, when I send the notification via PHP)

```
token:****
type:4
auth:****
certPassword:***
cert:****
body:Notification Test;Test Body
production:false
device:cn1-ios-****
```

For debugging, I don't have anything implemented in the push method of PushCallback. Notice, that it does not crash with type 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a regression due to the background notification work. I've filed an issue [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1798) to investigate/resolve it for the coming release.